# NullInjectorError: No provider for BsDropdownDirective

Tags: ngx-bootstrap

I keep getting this error in the browser console and the functionality of `bsdropdown` is not working. Below is the detailed error from the browser:

> main.ts:6 ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[BsDropdownDirective -> BsDropdownDirective -> BsDropdownDirective]:
> NullInjectorError: No provider for BsDropdownDirective!
> at NullInjector.get (core.mjs:7493:27)
> at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:7914:33)
> at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:7914:33)
> at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:7914:33)
> at ChainedInjector.get (core.mjs:12084:36)
> at lookupTokenUsingModuleInjector (core.mjs:3201:39)
> at getOrCreateInjectable (core.mjs:3246:12)
> at Module.ɵɵdirectiveInject (core.mjs:10041:12)
> at NodeInjectorFactory.BsDropdownToggleDirective_Factory [as factory] (ngx-bootstrap-dropdown.mjs:25:102)
> at getNodeInjectable (core.mjs:3431:44)

I have added in **app.module.ts**:

```
 BrowserAnimationsModule,
    BsDropdownModule.forRoot()
```

Below is the component HTML where I am using the dropdown:

```
<div *ngIf="(!!loggedIn())" class="dropdown mr-5">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle text-light" dropdownToggle (click)="false">
        Welcome {{loggedinUser}}
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" *dropdownMenu>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">
            <i class="fas fa-tachometer-alt">
            </i>
            View Dashboard
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">
            <i class="far fa-user-circle">
            </i>
            My Profile
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried updating angular cli, bootstrap and ngx-bootstrap however, the error still persists.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `providers: [BsDropdownDirective]` to your component